# SQL TYPE in pl/sql and type as a table

Tags: sql, object, plsql, user-defined-types

I am little confused with a creation of type as a table.

What does this line do?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE_TABLE AS TABLE OF OBJECT_ONE;
```

Here is how I have been using types as an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE AS OBJECT(
  NAME  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  AGE   VARCHAR2 (50 BYTE)
 );
```

and then run a statement:

```
DECLARE 
   COPY_OBJECT  OBJECT_ONE;

 BEGIN 
    COPY_OBJECT := OBJECT_ONE ('kgo','MONDAY','25')
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COPY_OBJECT.NAME ||' ' ||  COPY_OBJECT.WEEK || 
       COPY_OBJECT.AGE);
  end;
```

And that is how I have been using it now, I see people using the following statement:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE_TABLE AS TABLE OF OBJECT_ONE;
```

Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `OBJECT_ONE` is a single object, while `OBJECT_ONE_TABLE`  is a set of objects.

For example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE AS OBJECT(
  2    NAME  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  3    WEEK  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  4    AGE   VARCHAR2 (50 BYTE)
  5   );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE_TABLE AS TABLE OF OBJECT_ONE;
  2  /

Type created.
```

a single object:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     COPY_OBJECT  OBJECT_ONE;
  3  BEGIN
  4      COPY_OBJECT := OBJECT_ONE ('MIKIA','MONDAY','25');
  5      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COPY_OBJECT.NAME ||' ' ||  COPY_OBJECT.WEEK || COPY_OBJECT.AGE);
  6  end;
  7  /
MIKIA MONDAY25

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

a collection:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     COPY_OBJECT  OBJECT_ONE;
  3     tab          OBJECT_ONE_TABLE := OBJECT_ONE_TABLE();
  4  BEGIN
  5      tab.extend(2);
  6      COPY_OBJECT := OBJECT_ONE ('MIKIA','MONDAY','25');
  7      tab(1) := COPY_OBJECT;
  8      --
  9      COPY_OBJECT := OBJECT_ONE ('XXX','SUNDAY','33');
 10      tab(2) := COPY_OBJECT;
 11      --
 12      FOR I IN TAB.FIRST .. TAB.LAST LOOP
 13          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i || ' - ' || tab(i).NAME ||' ' ||  tab(i).WEEK || ' ' || tab(i).AGE);
 14      END LOOP;
 15  end;
 16  /
1 - MIKIA MONDAY 25
2 - XXX SUNDAY 33

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I would recommend reading something about collections, there's so much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> what does this line do in Pl/sql?
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE_TABLE AS TABLE OF OBJECT_ONE;
> ```

This line states that you have created a user defined type of your newly defined Object datatype which is suppose to hold data like a `table`. So when you wrote this line in your code, `PLSQL` compiler knew that you had defined a new userdefined table collection which is suppose to hold records just like a normal table.

Now you would be thinking what the use of below:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE AS OBJECT(
>   NAME  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
>   AGE   VARCHAR2 (50 BYTE)
>  );
> ```

Now when you declared this type , it means you created a structure of your new userdefined datatype. It is similar to `C++` structures where you create a structure having differnt datatype clubbed together, to use it as  your own datatype.

Now if i look at your object definition and your code posted below, so the first impression i get is a `Failure`. You object has `2` columns and while assigning value to you variable, tried to pass on `3` variables. So that should result in failure saying `"PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OBJECT_ONE'"`

> ```
> DECLARE 
>    COPY_OBJECT  OBJECT_ONE;
>
>  BEGIN 
>     COPY_OBJECT := OBJECT_ONE ('MIKIA','MONDAY','25')
>       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COPY_OBJECT.NAME ||' ' ||  COPY_OBJECT.WEEK || 
>        COPY_OBJECT.AGE);
>   end;
> ```

Correcting your code, you can see that here you declared a single variable of your Object type and assigned value to it , which in general is not widely used since you cannot assign multiple times same variable to hold multiple rows. So if the task is to assign multiple set of rows to the variable, then you would need the statement shown below.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2       COPY_OBJECT      OBJECT_ONE;
  3  BEGIN
  4       COPY_OBJECT := OBJECT_ONE ('MIKIA', '25');
  5       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (   COPY_OBJECT.NAME || ' ' || COPY_OBJECT.AGE);
  6  END;
  7  /
MIKIA 25

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So here you want a number of rows to be inserted to your userdefined table, you would had to add the next step shown below:

> `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJECT_ONE_TABLE AS TABLE OF OBJECT_ONE;`

```
DECLARE
     --Defining and initializing
     COPY_OBJECT      OBJECT_ONE_TABLE :=OBJECT_ONE_TABLE ();
BEGIN
     ---Exteding(3) means i state the collection to hold 3 records. I
     --if you dont define then there would not be any limit of records which a collection can hold

     COPY_OBJECT.Extend(3); 
     --Adding rows to your userdefined table
     COPY_OBJECT(1) := OBJECT_ONE ('MIKIA', '25');---First row of the collection table
     COPY_OBJECT(2) := OBJECT_ONE ('SEROW', '26');---Second row of the collection table
     COPY_OBJECT(3) := OBJECT_ONE ('THIRD','27');---Third row of the collection table

     FOR I in 1..COPY_OBJECT.COUNT
     LOOP

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( COPY_OBJECT(i).NAME || ' ' || COPY_OBJECT(i).AGE);

     END LOOP;
END;
```

And Output you get :

```
SQL> /
MIKIA 25
SEROW 26
THIRD 27

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```